# POST to my localhost on port 5587

Tags: c#, post, get, localhost

I want to be able to write code that interacts with an app running on my computer which is listening on port 5587.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HttpPost("http://localhost:5587", "/send/?username=testingname&password=testingpw");
}

public static string HttpPost(string URI, string Parameters)
{
    System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URI);
    req.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
    //Add these, as we're doing a POST
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.Method = "POST";
    //We need to count how many bytes we're sending. Params should be name=value&
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Parameters);
    req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream();
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); //Push it out there
    os.Close();
    System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    if (resp == null) return null;
    System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
    resp.Close(); 
    return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
}
```

When I read the specs on the app, it says:

1) The POST **request** should be:

> http://HOST:PORT/send/? 
>          username=user&
>          password=pw& 
>          to=destination& 
>          bcc=bccDestination&
>          subject=messageSubject

2) And also the POST **data** should be:

> message=messageBody

3) Also, this POST request returns a UUID of the message in the queue. This UUID is used later for checking the status of messages in the queue.

How might I change this code to pull off the three things there that I need to do including getting a response back with an ID so I can save it for later?

---

EDIT:

[image]There is a screen shot of what the output I need looks like versus the output that I am currently putting out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query string parameters should be part of the uri string, and a message needs to be set in the request body

Call it like this

```
string uuid = HttpPost("http://localhost:5587/send/?username=user&password=pw&to=destination&bcc=bccDestination&subject=messageSubject", "message=hi there");
Console.WriteLine(uuid);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Change last two lines of HttpPost method to

```
string uuid = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
resp.Close(); 
return uuid;
```

Of course you will need to change the parameters values to those that are valid

Comment: Correct answer - only other thing I'd add is that they are closing the request before they have read it. You cannot resp.Close() before you have read the stream.

Comment: Thank you, Bhavo. I have amended the code as you suggested. It is now obvious that I was using this function incorrectly and calling it all wrong. Also, thank you and Jacob for catching that close() call I had there at the bottom. I was not even to the point of hitting that in the code because I was (and still am) getting this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine

I have googled this and found a few answers, but none of them worked....

Comment: One of the solutions was the update the config file and do what appears as just sweeping the error under the rug and eating it globally. I'd rather just fix whatever it is trying to tell me. Oh, and that error occurs on the System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse(); line down near the end. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Is your service working, you can use fiddler to send a request to see if its ready to go.

Comment: Looks like your app isn't responding correctly, Response status isn't being set in response looks like, you can debug and look at the response detail being sent back, or use fiddler.

Comment: I just ran fiddler on it and it sends back the ID just fine. Man, this is so close. Any idea?

Comment: What's the raw response look like in fiddler?, add to your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82765/discussion-between-fujibob-and-bhavo).

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd like to say that **HttpClient** is much more efficient and simple than **WebRequest**.

For this code to work with HttpClient, you'll need to:

1.Add the NuGet package **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client** (Tools>NuGet Package manager>Manage NuGet packages for solution).

2.Create Request and Response classes, such as:

```
    public class RequestClass
    {
        public string message { get; set; }
    }

    public class ResponseClass
    {
        public string UUID { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, the method that does the POST request (using Generics and HttpClient):

```
    using System;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Net.Http.Headers;

    private static T PostData<T, P>(P postData, string uri, string path)
    {
        var ret = default(T);
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

                var response = client.PostAsXmlAsync(path, postData).Result;
                //var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(path, postData).Result; if your endpoint accepts json content
                ret = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Do something
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

The usage of this method is simple:

```
        var request = new RequestClass {messageBody = "Something"};
        var uri = "http://localhost:5587";
        var path = "/send?username=user&password=pw&to=destination&bcc=bccDestination&subject=messageSubject";
        var result = PostData<ResponseClass, RequestClass>(request, uri, path); //this will be of type ResponseClass which has the UUID property.
```

Keep in mind though, you need to know what content type does your endpoint support (json, xml,...) so you can specify it in the PostData() method.

Comment: Thank you for this! I got it to work ALMOST. I changed the var request line to have "message" instead of "messageBody" but that was all. Coincidentally, though, I cannot get it to send a message along with the POST. I have a listener on my localhost 5587 so I can see what goes in and it simply does the POST and the header info but I never see the message= part in there anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: Here is a screen shot of my data that was picked up by this listening app: http://i.imgur.com/TvisIsL.png    shouldn't the message= part have been there where the red arrow is?

Comment: can you share the code of your listener's endpoint? (e.g the _/save_ method)

Comment: try changing `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));` to `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));`

Comment: The listener app is closed off and third party. I cannot get access to its code. But it does respond well to Fiddler.

Comment: I also tried changing that line and, although there are no errors, it still never sends the message= part over to the listener. The listener app, which is a message sending app, just sends messages with all the right data but with no message in them.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/xls1qjr.png There is a screen shot of what the output I need looks like versus the output that I am currently putting out.